# JWT Validation policy suddently not valid when changed to a different audience with Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have a strange problem changing the value of audience element below for JWT validation within APIM, ref link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT

**1 new link:**
 https://new.onelogin.com/oidc/token

I only changed the value of audience element from the old version in 2. But I get the validation error below from APIM portal when I tried to save the policy:

```
The element 'validate-jwt' has invalid child element 'openid-config'. List of possible elements expected: 'required-claims'.
```

Please note that the old version in 2 doesn’t need the 'required-claims'  element.

client_id=new xxx

```
    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Error: expired token or invalid token" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
        <audiences>
            <audience>new xxx</audience>
        </audiences>
        <issuers>
            <issuer>https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc</issuer>
        </issuers>
       <openid-config url="https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    </validate-jwt>
```

**2 The old url and jwt validation**, and it works.

https://old.onelogin.com/oidc/token

```
     client_id=old xxx

    <validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Error: expired token or invalid token" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
        <audiences>
            <audience>old xxx</audience>
        </audiences>
        <issuers>
            <issuer>https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc</issuer>
        </issuers>
       <openid-config url="https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    </validate-jwt>
```

Any idea?

**Updates:**

Now even the original policy that was working has the issue even nothing has been changed:

```
The element 'validate-jwt' has invalid child element 'openid-config'. List of possible elements expected: 'required-claims'.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to move the `openid-config`up in the xml and keep it just under `validate-jwt`opening tag. Please see below:

```
<validate-jwt header-name="Authorization" failed-validation-httpcode="401" failed-validation-error-message="Unauthorized" require-expiration-time="true" require-scheme="Bearer" require-signed-tokens="true">
    <openid-config url="" />
    <issuer-signing-keys>
        <key>Base64 Encoded Key</key>
    </issuer-signing-keys>
    <audiences>
        <audience></audience>       
    </audiences>
    <issuers>
        <issuer></issuer>
    </issuers>  
</validate-jwt>
```

Comment: This is also true of the other policies. The order matters! It must follow the order specified in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT

Comment: One doesn't have to forget that in XML, order of the elements matters...